# supress_callback_exceptions = True no loger works

Tags: python-3.7, plotly-dash

In an older version of `Dash`, I used to need to be able to say,

```
supress_callback_exceptions = True
```

Since I upgraded to the new version of `Dash`, now I get an error on that line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dash-yahoo_options.py", line 2109, in <module>
    app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/envs/dash_apps_36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/_utils.py", line 81, in __setattr__
    self[key] = value
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/envs/dash_apps_36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/_utils.py", line 106, in __setitem__
    raise AttributeError(final_msg, key)
AttributeError: ('Invalid config key. Some settings are only available via the Dash constructor', 'supress_callback_exceptions')
(dash_apps_36) idf@ubvm:~/Downloads$ vi dash-yahoo_options.py
(dash_apps_36) idf@ubvm:~/Downloads$ python dash-yahoo_options.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dash-yahoo_options.py", line 2109, in <module>
    app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/envs/dash_apps_36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/_utils.py", line 81, in __setattr__
    self[key] = value
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/envs/dash_apps_36/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/_utils.py", line 106, in __setitem__
    raise AttributeError(final_msg, key)
AttributeError: ('Invalid config key. Some settings are only available via the Dash constructor', 'supress_callback_exceptions')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you missed it in the Dash change log, this misspelled fallback was removed in [1.0.0](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/c958eab7f2e3c88d0018b900d45b043308a9b22c/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-100---2019-06-20).

The configuration attribute should still supported (as at 1.6.0), you just need to use the right name.

```
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```

Comment: With dash version 1.14.0 I get the folowing

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\index.py", line 25, in <module>
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
  File "C:\python\zpython38_32\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1634, in run_server
    self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
  File "C:\python\zpython38_32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'suppress_callback_exceptions'